# Instantiate a java Collector<Row, ?,List> to call prepared statements from vertx reactivate

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, prepared-statement

I am trying to use [collector queries](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-pg-client/java/#_collector_queries) to read a database and get list of objects. I prepared following method.

```
public <T> Future<List<T>> queryForList(String query, Tuple parameters,
                                        Collector<Row, ?, List<T>> collector) {
    Promise<List<T>> promise = Promise.promise();
    this.pgPool.preparedQuery(query, parameters, collector, ar -> {
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            SqlResult<List<T>> result = (SqlResult<List<T>>) ar.result();
            if (result.rowCount() == 0) {
                promise.complete(Collections.emptyList());
                    return;
                }
                promise.complete((List<T>)result.value());
            } else {
                log.warn("Query execution failed. sql: {}, message: {}", 
                          query, ar.cause().getMessage());
                promise.fail(convertPgException(ar.cause()));
            }
        });
        return promise.future();
    }
```

but I am having trouble creating the test for this method. I need to define a collector pass on to the following test case having trouble to instaintiate the collector in the following test line.

```
@Test                                                                                                                 
public void returnsAsListUsingCollectors(TestContext ctx) {                                                                                                                                                                                 
    Collector<Row, ?, List<Temp>> collector = Collector.of(
        DataCollector::list,
        DataCollector::accept,
        DataCollector::combine,
        DataMapper::apply,
        DataCollector::charactoristics);

    this.subject.queryForList("select id,data from test_table where id in ($1, $2)",
                             Tuple.of(1, 2), collector)       
                             .setHandler(ctx.asyncAssertSuccess(res -> { 
                                 //verification of elements                                                               
                             }));                                                                                                      

}
```

Following methods are for the data collection and for data mapping. I get "Can not resolve apply" compilation error.

```
class DataMapper implements Function {                          

    @Override                                                   
    public Object apply(Object o) {                             
        String data = ((Row)o).getString("data");               
        String extra = ((Row)o).getString("extra");             
        return new Temp(extra, data);                           
    }                                                           
}                                                               

class Temp {                                                    
    String extra;                                             
    String data;                                              

    public Temp(String extra, String data){                     
          this.data = data;                                     
          this.extra = extra;                                   
    }                                                         
}                                                               

class DataCollector {                                           

    private List<Temp> tempList = new ArrayList<>();                                                                     

    public void accept(Temp o) {                                
        tempList.add(o);                                        
    }                                                           

    DataCollector combine(DataCollector collector){             
        this.tempList.addAll(collector.list());                 
        return this;                                            
    }                                                           

    public List<Temp> list(){                                   
        return this.tempList;                                   
    }                                                           

    public Set<Collector.Characteristics> charactoristics(){    
        return Collections.emptySet();                          
    }                                                           
}
```

Comment: what is the definition of `does not work`?

Comment: Good Question. Better phrasing would be I am having trouble getting the collector instance created to pass to the query for method in the test case. Basically I need to provide a Collector<Row, ?, List<T>> object which I don't know how to create. Probably I need to implement it my self or is there a easier way to handle it like in the case of a map.

Comment: can you show the error you get when you use `Collectors.toList()`?

Comment: funny. did you happen to read the _exact_ previous question for `java-8` tag? I showed how to define a custom collector there.

Comment: @Eugene Could you take a look at the updated question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start slow here. First, making raw classes is always a terrible idea, if you *know* that you are transforming from a `Row` to a `Temp`, specify it as such:

```
static class DataMapper implements Function<Row, Temp> {

    @Override
    public Temp apply(Row o) {
        String data = o.getString("data");
        String extra = o.getString("extra");
        return new Temp(extra, data);
    }
}
```

Though, as you soon will find out, you do not really need this `implements` part, it could be as simple as:

```
static class DataMapper {

    public static Temp apply(Row o) {
        String data = o.getString("data");
        String extra = o.getString("extra");
        return new Temp(extra, data);
    }
}
```

Then, grow the good habit to declare fields as `final` that are set in the constructor:

```
static class Temp {

    private final String extra;
    private final String data;

    public Temp(String extra, String data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.extra = extra;
    }
}
```

The main problem that you have is to define this custom collector and you are over-complicating things. If you want to use `Collector::of` - you have to look at its definition of `Row, ? List<Temp>`. This basically says : I will take some `Row`s (on at a time) as input and will transform them to `List<Temp>`. That is pretty much all *you* care about here. As such your collector can be defined as simple as :

```
 Collector<Row, ?, List<Temp>> collector =
        Collector.of(ArrayList::new,
                     (list, element) -> list.add(DataMapper.apply(element)),
                     (left, right) -> {
                         left.addAll(right);
                         return left;
                     },
                     Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH
 );
```

Comment: This is better than I hoped for. Thanks for the reply. I have been having trouble to get there as I don't really get the java lambdas and it confuses me left to right some times.